# Microsoft Word - Field help - bookmarks and cross reference within a table to a text paragraph

Tags: ms-word

I am trying to automate a word doc - i have a table in a word doc that when i update it i want to update the values from the table throughout the word doc in text paragraphs - i have set the entire value of a cell within a table as a bookmark - when I cross reference throughout the file it inserts the entire cell and not the values of the cell within the reference field - I know if I make the values within the cell the bookmark it works however the whole point of this is that you can delete the entire values within the cell and update them - when you do this the bookmark itself gets deleted so it doesn't allow the user to update.

I.e. is there any way to modify the Field formulas i.e = my current field code is { REF Bookmark_1} is there some kind of way to pull JUST the values of of bookmark_1 so a little cell doesn't get inputted??? Again i need this field in the table to be editable so i cant just bookmark the template placeholder data...

Comment: This would be better asked in the Super User forum. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word --- This forum is about coding, not use of software. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: See *Reference Table Cells From Outside The Table* in my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, available at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38720-microsoft-word-field-maths-tutorial.html